# Is there a way to ensure iPad Simulator landscape screenshots are rotated correctly?

Tags: ios, rotation, ios-simulator, screenshot, ios13

Most of the iPad apps I develop are used in Landscape mode. The iPad Simulator always starts in Portrait mode; with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> I rotate it to Landscape mode. In the past (before iOS 13.0 or 13.1), screenshots made with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> had the correct rotation, but if I make a screenshot right now it's rotated by 90 degrees.

[image]
<sub>(click to enlarge)</sub>

This is how the Mac desktop looks like when I make the screenshot on the Simulator:

[image]

Is there a way to stop this behaviour? I've tried the menu option Hardware -> Rotate Device Automatically but that didn't help.

Comment: I've encountered this too, but rotating the resulting screenshot is trivial so I didn't worry about it. Notice that the interface _is_ rotated (the status bar is in the correct place) so there's no issue here.

Comment: This is still broken in XCode 11.4. Same workflow. What makes it even more irritating is that if you then distribute that "fixed" screenshot it actually goes back to being incorrect in some cases.

Comment: UPDATE: Fixing the orientation in Preview seems to be more reliable than using Finder Markup. (This is verified when uploading screenshots to App Store Connect. When using Markup to fix the rotation they upload wrong, but when using Preview to fix the rotation they upload correctly.)

Comment: This issue has messed up my screenshots in the App Store!  Very frustrating.  Even rotating in preview or markup doesn't work - I upload the rotated screenshots to ASC, they look fine, but then when the app is published they're displayed in portrait mode and look distorted !!!  I created a support ticket for that but Apple hasn't reponded yet.  What a mess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to have been fixed with the release of iOS 14 / Xcode 12. Now, when I take a screenshot of my Simulator in Landscape mode, it is saved in Landscape orientation.